# how to validate input date with correct day in month and correct input for leap year in php

Tags: php

Hi I'm creating an appointment form which include input date which is i'm using drop down box for day, month and year. I managed to validate user to input 24 hours from today date, but if the user input something that are unavailable for any month eg. 31/06/2013, 31/09/2013, the form are successfully submit but, what i get from the post, it going to the month before such as when user key in 31/**06**/2013, the result i got 31/**05**/2013, same as the rest. As you can see the month are not correct.

what i have now is this code to validate;

```
$appointment_inputdate = mktime(0,0,0, intval($appointment_day), intval($appointment_month), intval($appointment_year));
$appointment_today = mktime(0,0,0, date("d"), date("m"), date("Y"));
```

for what i have now is only this but for incorrect date, I'm not sure how to make it

```
if ($appointment_inputdate <= $appointment_today) {
echo "
    <div style=\"background-color: #E00;\">
        Submission fail. Your appointment date must be at least 24 hours before. Please go back and change the date.
    </div>
    <input style=\"padding:10px 20px;margin-top:20px;\" type=button value=\"Back\" onClick=\"history.go(-1)\">
";
exit();
}
```

Comment: Interesting [solution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#107815).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wookai said check the date first.

Also you have got the order of the mktime inputs wrong.

See [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

> mktime ($hour, $minute,$second ,**$month, $day, $year**).

Edit:

To check the date update add:

```
if (!checkdate ((int)$month,(int)$day,(int)$year)) {
echo "
    <div style=\"background-color: #E00;\">
        Not a valid date;
    </div>
    <input style=\"padding:10px 20px;margin-top:20px;\" type=button value=\"Back\" onClick=\"history.go(-1)\">
";
exit();
}
```

You could try using jquery on the submitting form to help the user. See [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: I'll change it, but still i can't solve the problem, i've already search around still no clue can be found

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`checkdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function. It checks the validity of a date in the Gregorian calendar, and takes into account leap years:

```
bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )
```

For example:

```
<?php
var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000));
var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001));
?>
```

outputs

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

If the date is incorrect, you could easily add some basic rules to try and correct it (e.g. replace Feb 29 with Mar 1 if the year is not a leap year).

Comment: haha and I was going to write a custom checkdate function, **+1**

Comment: How do i implement it into the rules, i'm quite new in php actually.